# Does a race happen when using pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, fork, data-race

For example if I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int *ptr;

int
main(void)
{
 ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
 if (ptr == NULL)
 return (1);
 if (fork() == 0) {
     (*ptr)++;
     printf("in child process\n");
     printf("%d\n", *ptr);
}
 (*ptr)++;
 printf("%d\n", *ptr);
 return (0);
}
```

I was wondering when the child process is started and the memory is copied, is a copy of the pointer ptr created, or is the actual memory where it points to also copied. In short, I am wondering if a datarace will happen, between the child and the parent, or will each have a different copy of the pointer ptr pointing to different locations in memory, or will each have a different copy of the pointer with both pointing to the same location in memory.

wondering what happens when I fork while using pointers to store variables,

Comment: The child gets a complete, exact copy of the entire virtual address space. Pointers are stored in that space. They point to data within the space.  There can be no race.

Comment: `(*ptr)++;` has undefined behavior since haven't initialized the `int` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not result in a race. `fork()` creates a new process (not a thread) and has a copy of all the variables. From the man pages:

> fork() causes creation of a new process.  The new process (child
> process)
> is an exact copy of the calling process (parent process) except for the
> following:
>
> ```
>        •   The child process has a unique process ID.
>
>        •   The child process has a different parent process ID (i.e., the
>            process ID of the parent process).
>
>        •   The child process has its own copy of the parent's descriptors.
>            These descriptors reference the same underlying objects, so
>            that, for instance, file pointers in file objects are shared
>            between the child and the parent, so that an lseek(2) on a
>            descriptor in the child process can affect a subsequent read or
>            write by the parent.  This descriptor copying is also used by
>            the shell to establish standard input and output for newly
>            created processes as well as to set up pipes.
>
>        •   The child processes resource utilizations are set to 0; see
>            setrlimit(2).
> ```

Note that `(*ptr)++;` causes [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as `ptr` points to uninitialized memory.